# How to show $\int_{\mathbb{R}}{t \choose x}^2{x \choose t}~dx = 1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

Let
$${ a \choose b } = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(a-b+1)}$$
be the continuous extension of the binomial coefficient to non-integer arguments. I noticed this morning that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}{t \choose x}^2{x \choose t}~dx = 1$$
For all real $t \geq0$. I tried to simplify the integrand according to the propeties on the [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) page for the gamma function, though I don't see where to apply even the reflection formula to:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\Gamma(t+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)\,\Gamma(t-x+1)^2\,\Gamma(x-t+1)}~dx$$
To show that the above equals $1$. I couldn't find many similar questions on MSE about these sorts of integrals and am unfamiliar with how to approach them, so I bring this one here.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I might guess it would be fruitful to show a special case is 1, and then use Liebniz rule to show that the partial derivative of the integral with respect to $t$ is 0.

Comment: I missed the squared so my previous comment was irrelevant. I edited the formatting on the denominator slightly to better accentuate the square.

Comment: Repackaging what I wrote previously a little bit: $$\Gamma(t-x+1)\Gamma(x-t+1) = (t-x)\Gamma(t-x)\Gamma(x-t+1) = (t-x)\Gamma(1-(x-t+1))\Gamma(x-t+1)$$ so you can use the reflection formula, but then you're left with $\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(t-x+1)$ in the denominator. However.. $$\text{B}(x+1,t-x+1) = \dfrac{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(t-x+1)}{\Gamma(t+2)} = \dfrac{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(t-x+1)}{(t+1)\Gamma(t+1)}.$$ So you can reduce this integral to something like.. $$\int_{\Bbb R}\dfrac{\sin(\pi(x-t+1))}{\pi(t-x)(t+1)\text{B}(x+1,t-x+1)}\,dx$$ where $\text{B}$ is the beta function.

Comment: if you replace the integral by a summation the result still holds? this sort of problem in combinatorics may be helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531809/balls-and-urns-with-two-color-balls/3531980#3531980

Comment: @CameronWilliams do you think the integral you suggested could be done with Complex Analysis ?

Comment: @Zophikel it can.

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse what do you think will be a suitable contour I don't think a standard contour would work since $B$ is involved in our integrated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a direct application of the [Ramanujan's Beta integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.13.E4):
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}&\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\Gamma\left(a+x\right)\Gamma\left(b+x\right)\Gamma\left(c-x\right)\Gamma\left(d-x\right)}=\\
&\hspace{3cm}\frac{\Gamma\left(a+b+c+d-3\right)}{\Gamma\left(a+c-1\right)\Gamma\left(a+d-1\right)\Gamma\left(b+c-1
\right)\Gamma\left(b+d-1\right)}
\end{align} 
which is valid for $\Re\left( a+b+c+d \right)>3$.

Here, with
$a=1,b=1-t,c=1+t,d=1+t$, we have $a+b+c+d=4+t>3$ if $t>-1$, and thus
\begin{align}
I(t)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\Gamma(1+t)}{\Gamma(x+1)\,\Gamma(1+t-x)^2\,\Gamma(x-t+1)}\,dx\\
&=\Gamma(1+t)\frac{\Gamma(1+t)}{\Gamma(1+t)\Gamma(1+t)\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1)}\\
&=1
\end{align} 
as expected. Then, this result should hold for $t>-1$.